# Why List can remove a new object that is not instantiated

Tags: java, collections

```
List<Integer> useCases = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(useCases, 47, 48, 49, 50);
useCases.remove(new Integer(47));
```

Why can the integer object of the new instance match the int value of 47 in the useCase?

If instantiates multiple integer types of 47, do they all correspond to the value of 47 in the useCase, and can they all direct the list to remove the value of 47?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on what others have said, this code:

```
Collections.addAll(useCases, 47, 48, 49, 50);
```

is actually shorthand for this:

```
Collections.addAll(useCases,
    Integer.valueOf(47),
    Integer.valueOf(48),
    Integer.valueOf(49),
    Integer.valueOf(50));
```

because Lists cannot hold primitives, only objects.  When the compiler automatically translates primitives into their equivalent wrapper class values, we say the compiler “auto-boxes” them.

This line:

```
useCases.remove(new Integer(47));
```

does not mean “remove only this exact argument.”  It means “remove the first object which is equal to this argument.”

`new Integer(47)` is equal to `Integer.valueOf(47)`, according to the `equals` method of the Integer class, so Integer.valueOf(47) is the object which gets removed.

By the way, `new Integer` is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)).  Integer.valueOf and auto-boxing are its replacement.

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I want. But I have another question, the remove method is that even if the parameter you pass is a different object with the same value, remove can find the object existed with the same value in the ArrayList and delete it according to the value. Is that what it means?

Comment: Yes.  That is what “first object which is equal to this argument” means:  the first element in the List which is considered equal by the `equals` method is considered a match and is removed.  The same rule applies to the `contains` method.  in general, Collection classes use the `equals` method to determine whether an argument and a collection element match.

Answer (score 6):

First, when you pass a primitive int, such as 47, it is "auto-boxed" to an Integer with a value of 47. Second, the Integer.equals() method compares the primitive values.

Comment: Is that exist an integer object when I pass a primitive int(47) ?

Comment: @VisionYang addAll only takes references to objects i.e. wrappers, not primitives.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You mean that Integer automatically create an object with 47 when I use the addAll and it references the object included 47?

Answer (score 0):

As Steve11235 said, the equals() method compares the two objects.

```
public class Animal {

String name;
int live;

public Animal(String name, int live) {
this.name = name;
this.live = live;
}
```

}

And now:

```
Animal animal = new Animal("Monkey",15);
Animal animal2 = new Animal("Cat",15);
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
Collections.addAll(animals, animal,animal2);
animals.remove(new Animal("Cat",15);
```

This would not work because the equals method is not comparing the objects, it is only comparing the reference.

Comment: But animals.remove(new Animal("Cat",15)); isn't the newly created object different from animal2?   So you can use different objects with the same value to remove the animal2?

Comment: I just wanted to show you that you can't remove an existing object in the ArrayList with a new Object that has no overwritten equals method.

Comment: But why the Integer can?  Its equals method does not return an object.  When I create an Integer object with same value, that object created is that I have passed in the ArrayList, and does integer automatically create an object when I enter this value?

Comment: That is because the equals method of the integer is  comparing the number 47 different that my Animal class is comparing the two values "Cat" and 15.

Comment: Yes, you have created two different objects with the same value, so animals.remove(new Animal("Cat",15)) would not work. As an Integer, I have passed the value of 47 to ArrayList, and create an new object when I want to remove the value of 47 in the ArrayList, but it works, and aren't these two different objects?

Comment: Yes, the two values are different objects. But the Integer object compares these two values like this:https://hastebin.com/definirehu.java It compares the actual value, not the object value.

Comment: Yes, Integer compares the actual value. So why do I remove an object with a value of 47 that corresponds to the value of 47 in the ArrayList, and that 47 is not an object but a value?

Comment: Because it removes the first object that is equal to 47.